# Retrieve user's created db objects in Django views

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to retrieve user's created "Instances" db objects in views, I have successfully get and parsed for templates but in views I received complete object but not able to parse it, when I try to access it's models field it through an error as :

> 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'name'

Here's my code:
**Instances/models.py**

```
class Instance(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='instances')
name = models.CharField(max_length=255, name='name')
serverFile = models.TextField(default='', blank=False)
jsonPackageFile = models.TextField(default='', blank=False)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False)

class Meta:
    ordering = ['-created_at']
```

**Images/views.py**

```
class BuildImage(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
form_class = BuildImageForm
model = Image
template_name = 'images/buildImage.html'
success_url = 'user/gui'

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    objectlist = request.user.instances.all()
    return render(request, 'images/buildImage.html', {'form': forms.BuildImageForm,
                                                      'objectlist': objectlist})

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BuildImageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.cleaned_data
            form.instance.user = self.request.user
            form.instance.tagName = data['tagName'].lower()
            instance_name = data['instance']
            form.instance.instance =instance_name
            # writeFiles(request, name=instance_name)
            form.save()
            img = request.user.instances.filter(name=instance_name)
            print(img)
            print(img.name)
        else:
            print(form.errors)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('users:gui'))
```

> print(img) display `<QuerySet [<Instance: Instance object>]>` in console.But **print(img.name)** throw an error as `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'name'`

Answer (score 2):

Your code returns a queryset. You need change this :

```
img = request.user.instances.filter(name=instance_name)
```

For this:

```
img = request.user.instances.get(name=instance_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is because, `img` is a queryset. If you want to print out the names, then do it in a loop,

```
for image in img:
    print(image.name)
```

or,

```
print(img[0].name) #if you want the first instance's name.
```